# openCV - Diferenciar fotos RGB e P&B em um diretório

Tags: python, imagem, opencv, rgb

Olá, Bom dia.

Possui um diretório (linux) com milhares de fotos, e preciso separar as coloridas das em preto e branco. Criei o algoritimo para varrer todos os arquivos e movê-los para uma pasta específica. Entretando, não estou conseguindo criar a condição para verificar se a imagem é colorida ou não. Alguém poderia me dar uma solução? Obrigado

Comment: No caso, você tem como ler a cor dos pixels da foto? OU já pensou em como comparar o código das cores?

Comment: Olá! Seria interessante você ler esse artigo sobre como fazer uma boa pergunta, para que tenha uma ajuda mais rapidamente e de forma direcionada. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Se tu conseguir ler os o valor rgb dos pixels, da para fazer 3 if's no código rgb e saber se o tom de cor é mais próximo do preto, e depois fazer os tres if's pro tom de cor branco. E repetir isso para cada pixel dentro da imagem.

Comment: Olá, Edward Ramos. Muito obrigado pela resposta. Acho que essa solução será válida, vou testar. Estava procurando alguma função já pronta que fazia isso automaticamente, mas não encontrei.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu encontrei uma maneira de verificar com o módulo `PIL ImageStat` ([Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068945/detect-if-image-is-color-grayscale-or-black-and-white-with-python-pil)).

```
from PIL import Image, ImageStat

MONOCHROMATIC_MAX_VARIANCE = 0.005
COLOR = 1000
MAYBE_COLOR = 100

def detect_color_image(file):
    v = ImageStat.Stat(Image.open(file)).var
    is_monochromatic = reduce(lambda x, y: x and y < MONOCHROMATIC_MAX_VARIANCE, v, True)
    print file, '-->\t',
    if is_monochromatic:
        print "Monochromatic image",
    else:
        if len(v)==3:
            maxmin = abs(max(v) - min(v))
            if maxmin > COLOR:
                print "Color\t\t\t",
            elif maxmin > MAYBE_COLOR:
                print "Maybe color\t",
            else:
                print "grayscale\t\t",
            print "(",maxmin,")"
        elif len(v)==1:
            print "Black and white"
        else:
            print "Don't know..."
```

As constantes COLOR e MAYBE_COLOR são opções rápidas para encontrar as diferenças entre as imagens coloridas e em escala de cinza, aparentemente não são seguras. 
Como exemplo, algumas imagens em JPEG que são vistas como cor, mas em real são em tons de cinza com alguns artefatos de cor devido a um processo de digitalização.

Comment: Olá, Geilton. Muito obrigado pela resposta. Testarei também.

Comment: Testei aqui, e para meus propósitos, funcionou bem. Obrigado, Geilton

Comment: @user157401 que bom que deu certo, quando possivel aceite a resposta. Obrigado